# How to sort an array of an array of objects by those objects attributes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sorting, object, nsmutablearray

If have an NSMutableArray foo of an NSMutableArray bar of objects. Each of the objects have a property that is a numerical value. In each NSMutableArray bar I want to sum this numerical property of each object. Then I want to sort the NSMutableArray foo by this sum. What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NSSortDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html).